# Printrbot Simple + OctoPrint on PC not working

Tags: calibration, motor, octoprint

I am running the newest version of OctoPrint server on my Windows 10 PC, and accessing it with Mozilla Firefox on the same PC.

I also installed Cura 15.04 and selected the Printrbot Simple profile, and pointed to the Cura install path in the OctoPrint client so that it can use it for slicing.

I plugged in my printer and it was recognized by OctoPrint. The nozzle temperature is correctly shown, and I can turn the fans on/off in the control tab.

However, I cannot do anything else in the control tab, including moving the axes. I have not imported any sort of printer profile into OctoPrint, since I cannot figure out how to or where to find my printer's information.

There has not been any kind of calibration process I can find either.
Can anybody help me find a print profile/calibrate my printer, and just get it working so I can move the axes/print something out?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: What does `octoprint.log` say in terms of errors?

Comment: octoprint.log has 0 errors in it. When I look in the Gcode console, all of the G28 (homing axis) all have "ok" as a response. No errors can be found anywhere. The printer just doesn't move aaaa

Answer (score 3):

Before any axis can move the printer must be homed correctly (`G28` command, or an equivalent home button, there are 2: an X/Y and a Z button). A correct printer profile must also be defined; this profile contains some bed geometry and speed data, these are some basic values that are easy to add through the wrench button and "printer profiles" menu item.

Note that Cura 15.04 is **very** old, more recent version with far more options and better stability can be downloaded, but won't work integrated in OctoPrint, instead you download the most recent version of Ultimaker Cura directly from Ultimaker.com slice your product and store the G-code file to later import this into OctoPrint.

Please take care in choosing an optimal power plan in Windows 10, if your computer goes to sleep during a print (or updates or crashes) your print is lost; using a Raspberry Pi is far more safe.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have not defined a profile yet, I will have to figure that out. The homing buttons do nothing for me currently, so that is hopefully due to not having a profile set up yet.

Comment: I have defined a profile.
Using both the G28 command and the homing button, nothing happens. No error in terminal (I recieve an "ok") and nothing out of the ordinary in octoprint.log. Fans can turn on and off thats it